# handling utf-8 string gtk

Tags: c++, stl, utf-8, gtk

How can i handle utf-8 string using gtk frame work.

Comment: You'll need to provide much more detail about what you're trying to do and what problems you're having.

Comment: GTK uses UTF-8 strings from glib, what is your actual question?

Comment: how to get stl string from ustring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use the following api:

`std::string    Glib::locale_from_utf8 (const Glib::ustring& utf8_string)`

Take a look at these pages:

- [glibmm: Character Set Conversion](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glibmm/unstable/group__CharsetConv.html)
- [UTF-8 and Glib::ustring](http://library.gnome.org/devel/libxml++-tutorial/stable/ch01s02.html)